# Insert into html code image and href from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, tags, echo

I have 1 table with 2 columns :
 1 called url (varchar 300)
 1 called image (BLOB)

I already make the upload and make the image show up on website, but I have another problem I want to have a  tag that can be used on image, I have this

```html
<?php echo ("<a href={$row['url']}>.<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($row['imagem']).'"/></a>); ?>
```

can someone help me out ??

Comment: See that you wrote $row['imagem'] instead of $row['image']

Comment: is this "working" code? escaping quotes does not look correct?

Comment: @user2342558 oh my bad the colum is called imagem, the problem is with the " and the ' because I am kind of begginer and i dont know how to use the \ in echo

Comment: @LeszekRepie yes I think that is the problem like I said I dont know how to use the \ on echos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the quotes is.

```
echo ("<a href='" . $row['url'] . "'><img src='data:image/png;base64," . base64_encode($row['imagem']) . "'/></a>");
```

Comment: Thank you, you really help me mate